# Using ASP.NET AJAX PageMethods and Validators

Tags: asp.net-ajax, validation

I have a basic CRUD form that uses PageMethods to update the user details, however the Validators don't fire off, I think I need to manually initialize the validators and check whether the validation has passed in my javascript save method. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally solved this: You need  to  call `Page_ClientValidate()` in your Save javascript method and If it returns true continue with the save, the `Page_ClientValidate()` initiates the client side validators, See code below:

```
    function Save()
    {
        var clientValidationPassed =Page_ClientValidate();
        if(clientValidationPassed)
        {
            //Save Data
            PageMethods.SaveUser(UserName,Role,SaveCustomerRequestComplete, RequestError);
            $find('editPopupExtender').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            //Do Nothing as CLient Validation messages are now displayed
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you using for development? VS 2008 supposedly has better JS debugging, haven't tried it yet.

For Ajax you can use the Sys.Debug obj

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/), you can use the [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) plugin.  It has great [javascript debugging support](http://getfirebug.com/js.html).